# analysing difference in variability between multiple related time series

Tags: time-series, variance

I have constant time series (yearly from 1950 to 2010) of the abundance of several species that were captured by different groups. These series are somewhat related because the quantity of all species captured is dependent on the same effort (which is not always the same each year, but evolves differently per group). Also, parts of the area were groups capture species is common ground.

My data looks like this: Year | group | species | abundance

How can I analyse the variability (variance) in abundance between species and groups? So I would want to know for which species the captures fluctuate more heavily, independent of the groups. And the inverse for the groups.

I could calculate the variance of each series (per species and per group) and then do an anova, but this wouldn’t take into account the dependence of the data,… Also, I already performed crosscorrelations, autocorrelations, spectrum analyses,… for other purposes, but I can’t find anything to answer my question.

Could I have a sort of ordered list output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing is to run separate models for each species, get the residuals, square them and look at cross correlations and coherence measures. Squaring residuals will get you the variances. You can also look at correlations of squared residuals series and the level of other species. Maybe the variability depends on the capture level in this or other periods.

You could get fancy and run something like GARCH, which models variance stochastically. This model will give you an estimate of the time varying variance, which you can again cross-correlate to other species etc.

This is all in realm of exploratory analysis. Once you do this, it may give you more ideas in terms of modeling all species simultaneously, maybe in vector autoregression (VAR) or state-space model framework. The latter is interesting because it can model hidden (unobservable) factor, which may impact all series at once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although both are really useful, I think yours is the easiest and most understandable. Just, if you say run a separate model for each species, does it matter a lot which kind?

Comment: It does matter, but it depends on your data. I wouldn't know what are the models in your field

Answer (score 0):

Throwing out an idea here, but what about having the time series as realisations of Gaussian processes? In particular the covariance functions would be parameterised by the species and group. Depending on the kernel function used, the values learned about the parameters would indicate how the smoothness of the timeseries depended on the group and on the species. Something like:

$K(x,x')=\exp\{ -\frac{(x-x')^2}{(\theta_g \gamma_s)^2}\}$

Where $\theta_g$ and $\gamma_s$ are parameters to be learned about the effects of the $s^{th}$ species and $g^{th}$ group respectively.

I'd be interested if anyone else's thoughts on the above.